# HP QTP Crashing or Running Super Slowly

Tags: qtp

Can somebody please advise if there's a way to prevent HP QTP from crashing and to speed it up?

Current Version: 12.02
OS: Windows 10 64-bit
Memory: 16GB

Thanks!

Comment: Version 12.02 is six years old, have you checked with a more current version?

Comment: @Motti Thanks, our organization doesn't have any newer version approved yet, but I'll see if there's a way to request it anyways.

Comment: AFAIK the license for UFT isn't version specific, once you have a license you should be able to upgrade with no additional cost, just download a newer version from MicroFocus's site and the license should work.